# Browserify and babelify works locally, but not on live website

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, browserify

I'm building a project in React and Javascript, and I'm building with Browserify and Babelify, outputting a `bundle.js` file. When I run `index.html` locally, everything like Bootstrap, fonts, and CSS files are loaded properly. But after submitting it to Github Pages onto my custom domain, everything's messed up - images are everywhere, no formatting, Bootstrap is clearly not loaded. I'm assuming the file path got messed up, but why?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/stylesheet/style.scss"> # The path only works locally
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is your local served over `file://`? Try to mimic GitHub pages' URL structure, and serve from an actual server like *xampp* or *wamp*. These sorts of issues are often due to incorrect relative URLs.